# why my defined <button onclick=function()> cannot work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, onclick

I try to do something that list out all the topic that is in my database then there is a button besides them to allow me to delete or update the question inside the topic. So I add the onclick function with a unique parameter. But it does not show any messages when I click on the delete button. Pls help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php 
        require "connectPHP.php";

        // to get the total number of topic present

        $counter = "SELECT COUNT(IdTopic) FROM TOPIC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $counter);
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $totalTopic = $row['COUNT(IdTopic)'][0];
        }
        $totalTopic = (int)$totalTopic;

    ?>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <br>
        <div class="collection">
            <br>
            <div class = "collectionContainer">
                <br>
                <div>
                    <?php
                        require "connectPHP.php";
                        $selectDataFromTopic = "SELECT * FROM TOPIC ORDER BY LENGTH(IdTopic), IdTopic";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$selectDataFromTopic);         // query
                        echo "<table id='topicTable'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
                            echo "<tr class='tableHeader'>";
                                echo "<th style='width:10%;'>IdTopic</th>";
                                echo "<th style='width:15%'>Sub topic</th>";
                                echo "<th style='witdh:55%'>title</th>";
                                echo "<th style='witdh:10%'>Delete</th>";
                                echo "<th style='witdh:10%'>change</th>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                                
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results

                                //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['IdTopic'] . "</td>";  
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['subTopic'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";

                                    $D_position = "D".$row['IdTopic'];
                                    echo "<td><button type='submit' class='deleteButton' id='".$D_position."' onclick='delete('".$D_position."')'> Delete</button></td>";

                                    $C_position = "C".$row['IdTopic'];
                                    echo "<td><button type='submit' class='changeButton' id='".$C_position."' onclick='change('".$C_position."')'> Change question </button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }

                        echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
                    ?>
                </div>
                <script>
                

                function delete(deletePositon){
                    confirm( "It will be deleted");
                }

                function change(changePosition){
                    // add some code here
                }
                        
                </script>

            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: This has obviously nothing to do with PHP. Please click `edit` and then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] with ONLY RENDERED HTML and script. No PHP

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with quoting. You're generating `onclick='delete('D100')'`. That's treated as 3 separate attributes `onclick='delete('`, `D100` and `')'`

Comment: @mplungjan PHP is certainly part of the problem, since it has to do with how they're substituting variables into the HTML.

Comment: When they post rendered HTML, it becomes obvious there is a quote issue. Anyway to get rid of that, see my answer

Comment: @mplungjan True, but then you won't see the sourcce of the problem that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Quotes are the initial problem
2. Delegation with data attributes is the solution
3. Also try to cut down on the echo. Use heredoc or my suggestion below

You can use fetch in the two functions

You need the PHP buttons to look like this

```
<td><button type='button' class='deleteButton' data-id='<?= $D_position ?>'> Delete</button></td>
```

Code after rendering

```js
const deleteRow = id => {
  console.log("Deleting", id);
};
const changeRow = id => {
  console.log("Changing", id);
};
document.getElementById('topicTable').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("deleteButton")) deleteRow(tgt.dataset.id);
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("changeButton")) changeRow(tgt.dataset.id);
})
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="collectionContainer">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class='tableHeader'>
          <th style='width:10%;'>IdTopic</th>
          <th style='width:15%'>Sub topic</th>
          <th style='witdh:55%'>title</th>
          <th style='witdh:10%'>Delete</th>
          <th style='witdh:10%'>change</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='topicTable'>

        <tr>
          <td>IdTopic 1</td>
          <td>subTopic 1</td>
          <td>title 1</td>

          <td><button type='button' class='deleteButton' data-id='$D_position1'> Delete</button></td>

          <td><button type='button' class='changeButton' data-id='$C_position1'> Change question </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>IdTopic 2</td>
          <td>subTopic 2</td>
          <td>title 2</td>

          <td><button type='button' class='deleteButton' data-id='$D_position2'> Delete</button></td>

          <td><button type='button' class='changeButton' data-id='$C_position2'> Change question </button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="collectionContainer">
    <div>
      <?php
                        require "connectPHP.php";
                        $selectDataFromTopic = "SELECT * FROM TOPIC ORDER BY LENGTH(IdTopic), IdTopic";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$selectDataFromTopic);         // query
                        ?>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class='tableHeader'>
              <th style='width:10%;'>IdTopic</th>
              <th style='width:15%'>Sub topic</th>
              <th style='witdh:55%'>title</th>
              <th style='witdh:10%'>Delete</th>
              <th style='witdh:10%'>change</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id='topicTable'>
            <$php while($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //Creates a loop to loop through results //$row[ 'index'] the index here is a field name 
             $D_position="D" .$row[ 'IdTopic']; 
             $C_position="U" .$row[ 'IdTopic']; ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $row['IdTopic'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['subTopic'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['title']</td>
                <td><button type='button' class='deleteButton' data-id='<?= $D_position ?>'> Delete</button></td>
                <td><button type='button' class='changeButton' data-id='<?=$C_position ?>'> Change question </button></td>
            </tr>
              <?php } ?>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: But the number of topic is unknown so how can I use php code to generate certain number of row of table with the button beside it?

Comment: @SzeYuSim The PHP loop that creates all the topics is the same, it just doesn't need the inline `onclick` attributes.

Comment: in my browser, it says deleting undefined

Comment: Then you did not do the PHP `$D_position="D" .$row[ 'IdTopic']; ` or the button `<button type='button' class='deleteButton' data-id='<?= $D_position ?>'> Delete</button>` correctly. Please show me the rendered button with the ID filled

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting the arguments to `delete()` and `change()` properly.

I find that it gets confusing when you use concatenation because of the mix between the quotes needed for PHP, HTML, and JavaScript. It's much easier to get if you substitute the variables directly into the PHP string. Since the HTML attributes are delimited with single quotes, you need to use double quotes around the function arguments. These double quotes need to be escaped because the PHP strings are enclosed in double quotes.

```
$D_position = "D".$row['IdTopic'];
echo "<td><button type='button' class='deleteButton' id='$D_position' onclick='delete(\"$D_position\")'> Delete</button></td>";

$C_position = "U".$row['IdTopik'];
echo "<td><button type='button' class='changeButton' id='$C_position' onclick='change(\"$U_position\")'> Change question </button></td>";
```

Note that since the arguments are the IDs of the buttons themselves, you could avoid this problem entirely by using `delete(this)` and `change(this)`. The functions should then be changed to treat the argument as a DOM element rather than ID (they just won't need to call `document.getElementById()`).

I also changed the HTML to use `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'`. Otherwise, clicking on the button will submit the form after the functions return.